# When aggregating rows in bigquery, I want to prioritize certain keywords and extract different columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to aggregate this table by id as shown below. The priorities are gold, silver, bronze, in that order, referring to the "type column".

priorities: gold > silver > bronze

## before

| id | type | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gold | banana |
| 1 | silver | apple |
| 2 | silver | orange |
| 2 | bronze | avocado |
| 3 | gold | kiwi |
| 3 | bronze | blueberry |

## after

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana |
| 2 | orange |
| 3 | kiwi |

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_agg`:

```
select id, array_agg(text order by length(type) limit 1)[offset(0)] as text
from mytable
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select id, 
  array_agg(text order by strpos(',bronze,silver,gold,', ',' || type || ',') desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as text
from `project.dataset.table`
group by id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Another way is

```
select id, text 
from `project.dataset.table`
where true
qualify row_number() over(partition by id order by strpos(',bronze,silver,gold,', ',' || type || ',') desc) = 1
```

with same output

Comment: Probably it is `strpos('gold,silver,bronze', type)` instead.

Comment: of course! Thank  you for checking @SergeyGeron !